# (x,y) graph in Python with different colours depending on y value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is my first post and I am new to Python.
I have a .dat file with 2 columns. I can plot it OK, but I want to have the same graph with colour that depends on the y value.

For this reason I am scanning the whole file, reading the y value and depending on the y value I append it and its corresponding x argument on new lists and then I plot them.

However I don't get the same graph.

Here's my code.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Blackx=[]
Blacky=[]
Bluex=[]
Bluey=[]
Redx=[]
Redy=[]
x,y=np.loadtxt('input.dat',unpack=True)
for t,i in zip(x,y):
    if i<=16966:
       Blacky.append(i)
       Blackx.append(t)
    elif i>=16967 and i<=17180:
         Bluey.append(i)
         Bluex.append(i)
    else:
         Redx.append(t)
         Redy.append(i)

plt.plot(Blackx,Blacky,'black')
plt.plot(Bluex,Bluey,'b')
plt.plot(Redx,Redy,'r')
plt.show()
```

The problem is that i get a different graph with 3 colours but it is not the same graph with plt.plot(x,y)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your post and attach the two plots you have? It would be much more easier to see what's going on since we do not have the data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your bluex is appending i not t, making the blue portion a (y,y) plot. do the red and black part look right and just blue wrong?